# 'try with resource' feature for File class

Tags: java, file-io, try-catch, java-7

I have one scenario where I am trying to implement with the Java 7 'try with resource' feature.

My finally block contains an object of `BufferedWriter` and `File`, which I want to close using 'try with resource' feature, instead of closing it by calling close method explicitly.

But I checked on net and saw that the `File` class does not implement the `AutoCloseable` interface, but `BufferedWriter` does. So how can I manage this scenario to implement 'try with resource' feature?

Comment: The File class doesn't have an open() method or a close() method, so why it should be auto-closable is a mystery. It is the BufferedInputStream that needs closing. Not a real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 try (BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path)))
```

Use this simply, br will be closed automatically.
 Eg. http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-write-to-file.shtml

Comment: So here you are saying that instead of creating a File object, I should directly pass the path of the file to the FileReader constructor and bypass the creation of File object.Right?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely, FileWriter provides a constructor like public FileWriter(String fileName)throws IOException
Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name.

Comment: See , this sample code :http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-write-to-file.shtml

Comment: @milind: you can still use a `File` object, if you wish. You don't need to close that at all!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to close a `File` because it's a pure Java object. It basically just holds the name of the file, nothing else (i.e. it does not require any OS resources to construct).

You only need to close your `BufferedWriter` and that is correctly `AutocCloseable`.

Comment: I was about to ask if a File object would left an opened file handle :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a BufferedWriter with File only, BufferedWriter requires a Writer, this how it should look like

```
    try (BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("file")))) {
        ...
    }
```

try-with-resources will call close only on BufferedWriter. Unfortunately BufferedWriter API does say that it closes the underlying writer, but in fact it does. As for File it has nothing to do with try-with-resources since it is not Autocloseable.

Comment: How this will help. Are you saying here that if I create the File object the way you have specified then when the control moves out of the try block BufferedWriter, FileWriter as well as File will automatically be closed?

Comment: @milind: then please don't forget to upvote any answer that helped you solve it and accept the one that helped most.

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer Ya thanks for reminding. I have upvoted on of the answer that helped me